# Assets are not loading anymore (maybe an update)

Tags: craft3, assets, error-message, plugin-imager, imagick

I just noticed that I can't see my files if I go into the assets section.
An Error blinks up and says "An unknown error occurred". In the front-end, I see every file and I can upload files to an asset too and see there uploaded files and selecting it.

The log file says nothing. 
I use for Image Transforms Imager without imgix.
If i want to edit an Image i get a error too:

> Getting unknown property: aelvan\imager\models\ConfigModel::imgixEnableAutoPurging

It has always worked.

I can only imagine that an update has changed something?!

Thanks for any help. Really big problem

Comment: I solved the edit Error with adding
public $imgixEnableAutoPurging = true;
public $imgixConfig = [];

to my imager config file. But it does not solve the problem for the asset section.

Comment: allright… It have something to do with my imager config file. If i delete it, it works!

Answer (score 1):

Solved the complete error with a reset of the imager config file.